# Security practice for web based systems

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sql-server-2008, security

So, it's finally time to look into the security of my software - the day I've been dreading!

I need to know the many many ways code can be hacked, taken advantage of, and How I can protect against it.

My system is an asp.net website which uses sql server 2008 (mostly stored procedures, but for asychnronous calls I directly insert the sql commands). I have a web service which polls multiple databases, I use external libraries(Including office interop), and allow for uploading and downloading files - without restriction.

My asp pages use javascript and jquery for most of their functionality.

I look forward to your response.

Comment: Look at the OWASP guides http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:How_To

Comment: *Security last* is not the bestest of practices ;-)

Comment: Secure internal intranet or external facing big bad world?

Comment: @Klaus :) I Know, but I thought I'd save the best for last. @gbn The big bad world - Hopefully only the ones who pay though..

Comment: I think you're asking a question that has such a broad response range. We don't know your site or how your project is built. We can't find specific security holes unless we had the project in front of us. You're going to have to spend some time reading on basic security principles (like the post by @Klaus). If you have *specific* questions, then please ask them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the security section on this [great SO community wiki post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72394/what-should-a-developer-know-before-building-a-public-web-site).